# Website displaying Bootstrap Screen Reader info (when it shouldn't be)

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-5

I'm building a new site, using some code I wrote for an old one, but incorporarting some slightly more sophisticated PHP includes and the code seems to behave differently on the two sites.

I have a bootstrap Navbar in both, that should auto-highlight the active page. I'm loading in the navbar from a .php layout file that detects which page is open and inserts the correct link:

```
               if($currentpage=="/rehearsal.php") 

                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/rehearsal.php">Rehearsal<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                 } else {
                 
                 echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/rehearsal.php">Rehearsal</a></li>';
                }
```

However on the new site I get the following (rehearsal should be highlighted black rather than having (current) next to it):

[image: rehearsal should be highlighted black rather than having (current)]

with the following Page Source:

[image]

However the other site displays as intended but has the same Page Source layout:

[image]

[image]

I'm guessing something elswhere in the code must be specifying this behaviour, but I'm not sure where to look. I've tried moving the inlude formats between sites and the problem persists. Here is the code for the problematic layout template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="room4.css">
    <title><?=$title?></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <header>
    <h1>Room4 Studios</h1>
  </header>
  <div>

  <?php 

$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        

?>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light" style="background-color: #68B3E2;">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="header_logo" src="images/logo.png" width="120" height="120" alt="..."></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <?php if($currentpage=="/index.php") 
    
                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                } else {
    
                echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php">Home</a></li>';
                }
                
                if($currentpage=="/rehearsal.php") 

                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/rehearsal.php">Rehearsal<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                 } else {
                 
                 echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/rehearsal.php">Rehearsal</a></li>';
                }
                
                if($currentpage=="/recording.php") 

                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/recording.php">Recording<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                 } else {
                 
                 echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/recording.php">Recording</a></li>';
                }

                if($currentpage=="/video.php") 

                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/video.php">Video<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                 } else {
                 
                 echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/video.php">Video</a></li>';
                }
                
                if($currentpage=="/hire.php") 

                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/hire.php">Hire<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                 } else {
                 
                 echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/hire.php">Hire</a></li>';
                }
                
                
                
                if($currentpage=="vouchers.php") 

                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="vouchers.php">Gift Vouchers<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                 } else {
                 
                 echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="vouchers.php">Gift Vouchers</a></li>';
                 }

                if($currentpage=="/contact.php") 

                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/contact.php">Contact<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                 } else {
                 
                 echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>';
                }

                if($currentpage=="/blog.php") 

                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/blog.php">Blog<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                 } else {
                 
                 echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/blog.php">Blog</a></li>';
                }
                ?>


                
                
                

            </ul>
            
              
              <a class="right_btn btn-primary btn-lg"  href="/booknow.php" role="button">BOOK NOW</a>
            
          </div>

          </div>
  
  

  <main>
  <?=$output?>
  </main>

  <footer>
  &copy; IJDB 2017
  </footer>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is how i reference it from the public site:

```
<?php

$title = 'Room4 Studios';

ob_start();

include  __DIR__ . '/../templates/rehearsal.html.php';

$output = ob_get_clean();

include  __DIR__ . '/../templates/layout.html.php';
```

Any help or insights would be much appreciated

Comment: The pages might have the same layout, but are they using the same version of Bootstrap? You tagged this `bootstrap-4` but are using "_bootstrap@5.0.1_". Please read https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#helpers, `.sr-only` has been renamed in 5.0

Comment: Thanks so much. Using .visually-hidden instead of .sr-only fixes the first problem. And delving a little deeper the way the Navbars work has changed between 4 & 5 and my code hasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Incase this helps anyone the problem was I was using code written for Bootstrap 4, and linking Bootstrap 5.

.sr-only is now .visually-hidden

&

and the active nav-bar is now referenced from within the <a tag rather than the <li tag:

```
<a class="nav-link active">
```

rather than

```
<a class="nav-link active">
```